# Preserve type hints (checked with mypy) for function decorated with aiocache's @cached decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting

Python version: 3.9.17

When I decorate a function with @cached, mypy will simply accept calls to the decorated function with invalid args. Making the typed params in the decorated function useless. How do I make mypy understand that it should flag calls to the decorated function that don't follow it's function signature?

aka:

```py
from aiocache import cached

@cached
def foo_cached(x: str) -> str:
  return x

def foo(x: str) -> str:
  return x

foo_cached() # mypy is fine with this.
foo() # mypy flags this, as it's missing arg for param 'x'.
```

looking for a solution that works for python 3.9

Comment: `aiocache.cached` doesn't have any type hints of its own, so `mypy` assumes that it (or more precisely, its `__call__` method, as it's a class) returns a value of `Any`. You would need to find or create a `.pyi` file that provides a type hint like `def __call__(self, f: Callable[P, T])) -> Callable[P, T]): ...`, where `P` and `T` are a `ParamSpec` and a `TypeVar`, respectively.

Comment: ParamSpec doesn't work in python 3.9 tho

Comment: You might be able to type-hint `cache.__new__` (not positive, since it's not being overriden) with something like `def __new__(cls, f: T) -> T`, to indicate that `cache` returns something of the same type as its argument. That's not strictly true, but it might work.